# How to track a zooming UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, zooming, caanimation

I have a zooming UIScrollView, and a non-zooming overlay view on which I animate markers. These markers need to track the location of some of the content of the UIScrollView (similar to the way a dropped pin needs to track a spot on the map as you pan and zoom).

I do so by triggering an update of the overlay view in response to the UIScrollView's `layoutSubviews`. This works, and the overlay tracks perfectly when zooming and panning.

But when the pinch gesture ends the UIScrollView automatically performs a final animation, and the overlay view is out of sync for the duration of this animation.

I made a simplified project to isolate this problem. The UIScrollView contains an orange square, and the overlay view displays a 2-pixel red outline around the frame of this orange square. As you can see below, the red outline always moves to where it should be, except for a short period of time after touch ends, when it visibly jumps ahead to the final position of the orange square.

[image: red line around a zooming rectangle]

The full Xcode project for this test is available here: https://github.com/Clafou/ScrollviewZoomTrackTest but all the code is in the two files shown below:

**TrackedScrollView.swift**:

```
class TrackedScrollView: UIScrollView {

    @IBOutlet var overlaysView: UIView?

    let square: UIView

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        square = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 300, width: 300, height: 300))
        square.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.addSubview(square)
        self.maximumZoomScale = 1
        self.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
        self.contentSize = CGSize(width: 500, height: 900)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        overlaysView?.setNeedsLayout()
    }
}

extension TrackedScrollView: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return square
    }
}
```

**OverlaysView.swift**:

```
class OverlaysView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var trackedScrollView: TrackedScrollView?

    let outline: CALayer

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        outline = CALayer()
        outline.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        outline.borderWidth = 2
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.addSublayer(outline)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if let trackedScrollView = self.trackedScrollView {
            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
            let frame = trackedScrollView.convertRect(trackedScrollView.square.frame, toView: self)
            outline.frame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectInset(frame, -3, -3))
            CATransaction.commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Among the things I tried was using a `CADisplayLink` and `presentationLayer` and this allowed me to animate the overlay, but the coordinates that I obtained from `presentationLayer` lagged slightly behind the actual UIScrollView, so this still didn't look right.  I think the right approach would be to tie my overlay update to the system-created UIScrollView animation, but I haven't had success hacking this so far.

How can I update this code to always track the UIScrollView's zooming content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIScrollView` sends `scrollViewDidZoom:` to its delegate in its animation block, if it's “bouncing” back to its minimum or maximum zoom when the pinch ends.  Update the frames of your overlays in `scrollViewDidZoom:` if `zoomBouncing` is true. If you're using Auto Layout call `layoutIfNeeded`.

`scrollViewDidZoom:` is only called *once* during the zoom bounce animation but adjusting your frames or calling `layoutIfNeeded` will ensure these changes are animated along with the zoom bounce, thus keeping them perfectly in sync.

Demo:

[image: demo of correct animation]

Fixed sample project: https://github.com/mayoff/ScrollviewZoomTrackTest

Comment: Neat! I had the impression that `scrollViewDidZoom:` was only called once, as opposed to at every step of the animation. I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: By the way, I sent exactly the same question with the same project and animated screenshot to Apple Developer Technical Support and this was their response: "Our engineers have reviewed your request and have determined that this would be best handled as a bug report". Stack 1 : Apple Support 0

Comment: Final note: the delegate's `scrollViewDidScroll:` also needs a similar implementation, because in some cases the animation is not a zoom but a pan that re-recenters the scrollview. And thank you so very much again Rob for your awesome answer!

Comment: This answer saved me *so* much time, I had a very similar issue to the OP and had also tried using a `CADisplayLink` to track the `presentationLayer` with the same issues. @Clafou: `scrollViewDidZoom:` is still only called once at the start of the bounce animation. However, calling `layoutIfNeeded` from `scrollViewDidZoom:` will make the layout adjustment animations happen in sync with the bounce animation.